# How to send multiple objects to socket in Java

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

Can anyone please advise how to send multiple serialized objects in java over a socket to a server?
currently my server gets always only the first object.

**Client side:**

```
public void communicate() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    carClientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
    carClientOR = new ObjectOutputStream(carClientSocket.getOutputStream());

    Car[] CarList = new Car[11];
    for ( int i = 1; i <=10; i++ ) {
        //Car alpha;
        CarList[i] = new Car("Alpha Romeo","GTI",1999+i);
    }
    for ( int i =1; i<= 10; i++) {
        carClientOR.writeObject(CarList[i]);
        carClientOR.flush();
        //carClientOR.reset();
    }
    carClientSocket.close();
}
```

**Server Side**

```
public void communicate() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
CarServerSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
    System.out.println("Server is ready and waiting for connection from client..\n");
    while (true) { 
        carSocket = CarServerSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Server Connected");
        carServerIR = new ObjectInputStream(carSocket.getInputStream());
        Car alpha1 = (Car) carServerIR.readObject();
        System.out.println("Object received from car clinet: " + alpha1.getCarBrad() + " " + alpha1.getCarModel() + " " + alpha1.getCarYear());
    }
    //carSocket.close();
    //CarServerSocket.close();
}
```

Comment: yeah... thats because you are only reading once... You need a loop to read.   `while((object = input.readObject()) != null)` Thats just a template of how you should be doing it

Comment: BRAVOֱ! working perfect with the for loop in the server side. i'm going to try the while idea.. thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem just make sure on client side you need to `output.writeObject(null)` when you want to end the reading so the loop kicks out

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the server side, due to the call `carSocket = CarServerSocket.accept();` being within the loop. It should be done once before the loop, and you should then get the other objects:

```
carSocket = CarServerSocket.accept();
while (true) { 
  System.out.println("Server Connected");
  carServerIR = new ObjectInputStream(carSocket.getInputStream());
  Car alpha1 = (Car) carServerIR.readObject();
  System.out.println("Object received from car clinet: " + alpha1.getCarBrad() + " " + alpha1.getCarModel() + " " + alpha1.getCarYear());
}
```

Comment: thanks but i got an exception when it tried that solution.

Comment: Moving the accept() outside the loop will result in ONLY a single client able to connect to the server side. Doubtful this is a desirable behavior.